# Помогите пожалуйста с ролями в discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

Как мне с помощью discord.js дать определённую роль всем пользователям у кого нет ролей?
Скажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == 'Community')

if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, role not found`)

message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).forEach(member => member.addRole(role))
```

`message.channel.send`(`**${message.author.username}**, role **${role.name}** was added to all members`)